# Image overlay/hover - YouTube video screenshot with play button - trouble with hover function

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a video screenshot with a play button image absolutely positioned over the screenshot. There's two classes; `.play` (the default) and `.fadeIn`.

I'm simply trying to "unfade" the play button when hovering over the screenshot. The only problem is when you hover over the actual button, it gets toggled because (I'm guessing) you're not actually hovering over the first image, so it gets treated as a mouse out event.

CSS:

```
.play {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65;
    top: 45;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="video" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqXi8WmQ_WM" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">
    <img src="../gs1.jpg" alt="YouTube" class="thumbnail" />
    <img src="../play-button-red@40.png" alt="YouTube" class="play"/>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function(){
        $(this).next('img').toggleClass('fadeIn');
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty stumped on this.

Comment: If I were you, I put the hover on the anchor tag and do it with css instead of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with jQuery, then I would bind the `hover` event to the `<a>` tag and target the image by class, like so:

```
$('.video').hover(function () {
    $('.play').toggleClass('fadeIn');
});
```

This could easily be done purely with CSS too.

Comment: If you got more than 1 video on a page, you can $(this).find('.play') instead of $('.play')